# ASP.Net Core 2 - Authentication timing out

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.Net Core 2 site running in an Azure app service.  My authentication seems to timeout randomly and return the user to the login screen (even if they had just been using a form less than a minute before).  It does not seem to occur at any specific time interval I can nail down (there is almost no load on the server).

I have added data protection, and then also tried to persist the keys to the file system as a test (this seemed to help the frequency but it could be a red herring).  I've set the authentication cookie to 24 hours with a sliding expiration and the session to 60 minutes.

I'm including my Startup in it's entirety so it's easier to see if I've borked something like an order up.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Wiki.Code;
using Wiki.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using System.IO;

namespace Wiki
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Protect the sessions from app pool recycles
            services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@".\"));

            // Authentication
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
                {
                    o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
                    o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Unauthorized");
                    o.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);                  
                });

            // Setup MVC and our security.
            services.AddMvc()
                    .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
                    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                    {
                        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Admin", "Admin");
                        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Editor", "Editor");
                    });

            // Add the ability to have a session.
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {                
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            });

            // This is for our data grid.
            services.AddMvcGrid();

            // Create our policies
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
                options.AddPolicy("Editor", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin", "Approved"));
            });

            // Get the AppSettings
            AppSettings settings = new AppSettings();
            Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(settings);
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(x => Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(x));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            var options = new RewriteOptions();
            options.AddRewrite("^article(.*)", $"/Article?href=article$1", false);
            app.UseRewriter(options);

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();
        }

    }
}
```

*Update:* Locally I was finally able to get this outside of the Azure environment.  Even though the cookie is set for a 24 hour expiration I received this after less than 15 minutes: "Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Ticket expired"

Comment: Is this an application you have upograded from core 1 to 2 by any chance?

Comment: No, it was started as a 2.0 site.

Comment: I'm investigating some authentication properties in the SignInAsync now that look promising as per the documentation.